# How to add JObject to Entity Framework as an object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a list of variables representing deserlialized json `jobject`s that I would like to add them to the entity database. How can I do this?

The solution attempted so far:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strtest);

foreach (var item in obj.results)
{
    db.ReedAPIModels.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Model class represents the database:

```
public class APIModel
{
        [Key]
        public int jobId { get; set; }
        public int employerId { get; set; }
        public string employerName { get; set; }
        public string employerProfileId { get; set; }
        public string employerProfileName { get; set; }
        public string jobTitle { get; set; }
        public string locationName { get; set; }
        public int minimumSalary { get; set; }
        public int maximumSalary { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string expirationDate { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string jobDescription { get; set; }
        public int applications { get; set; }
        public string jobUrl { get; set; }
}
```

API Results

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "jobId": 39650785,
      "employerId": 375315,
      "employerName": "Spectrum IT Recruitment (South)",
      "employerProfileId": null,
      "employerProfileName": null,
      "jobTitle": "Senior Front End Developer",
      "locationName": "Reading",
      "minimumSalary": 60000,
      "maximumSalary": 70000,
      "currency": "GBP",
      "expirationDate": "17/01/2020",
      "date": "03/01/2020",
      "jobDescription": " Senior Front End Developer - Reading, Berkshire  Senior Front End Developer required by a growing company based in Reading, Berkshire. The company are looking to recruit a Senior Front End Developer to join their expanding development team to work on the full design and development lifecycle of new products. The successful Senior Front End Developer will have lots of opportunities for development of both techni... ",
      "applications": 0,
      "jobUrl": "https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/senior-front-end-developer/39650785"
    }
  ],
  "ambiguousLocations": [],
  "totalResults": 9007
}
```

Also, I have tried to use `ToObject` method

Answer (score 0):

You should Add `APIModel` instead of `ReedAPIModels`.

Your can try this way

```
var apiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strtest);

foreach (var item in apiResult.results)
{
    db.APIModel.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: RooObject model is needed

Comment: also the key word result is needed in the foreach loop

Comment: Why don't you give me your sample `strtest` value, I assume that it should the same structure with `APIModel`

Comment: Yes, You ought to provide us the `API Results` at the beginning.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look and give it a try then feedback me @ghassa

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a RootObject model which can be created by this website: 
http://json2csharp.com/

```
    RootObject datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(strtest);

    foreach (var item in datalist.results)
    {
        db.APIModels.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```